# .ini file load environment variable

Tags: python, flask, ini, alembic

I am using [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for migrations implementation in a `Flask` project. There is a `alembic.ini` file where the database configs must be specified:

`sqlalchemy.url = driver://user:password@host/dbname`

Is there a way to specify the parameters from the environment variables? I've tried to load them in this way `$(env_var)` but with no success. Thanks!

Comment: @Oz123, `sqlalchemy.url =
$(DB_SERVICE):/$(DB_USER):$(DB_PASS)@$(DB_HOST)/$(DB_NAME)`

Comment: @dirn I am using sqlalchemy with declarative base, but as far as I know `Flask-Migrate` is compatible only with `Flask-SQLAlchemy`

Comment: You're right. I guess I just assumed you were using that. Why not set `sqlachemy.url` in `env.py` instead?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I've solved the problem by setting `sqlalchemy.url` in `env.py` as @dirn suggested.

`config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', <db_uri>)` did the trick, where `<db_uri>` can be loaded from environment or config file.

Comment: Are you able to provide more information to your solution? I'm not sure where this env.py file is.

Comment: @Cruncher In alembic directory of your project, see https://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: answer could be improved. should had specified that need "from alembic import context" command

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for a while how to manage this for mutli-databases

Here is what I did. I have two databases : **logs** and **ohlc**

According to the [doc](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-an-environment),
I have setup the alembic like that

```
alembic init --template multidb
```

### alembic.ini

```
databases = logs, ohlc
[logs]
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://botcrypto:botcrypto@localhost/logs
[ohlc]
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://botcrypto:botcrypto@localhost/ohlc
```

### env.py

```
[...]
# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
logger = logging.getLogger('alembic.env')

# overwrite alembic.ini db urls from the config file
settings_path = os.environ.get('SETTINGS')
if settings_path:
    with open(settings_path) as fd:
        settings = conf.load(fd, context=os.environ) # loads the config.yml
    config.set_section_option("ohlc", "sqlalchemy.url", settings["databases"]["ohlc"])
    config.set_section_option("logs", "sqlalchemy.url", settings["databases"]["logs"])
else:
    logger.warning('Environment variable SETTINGS missing - use default alembic.ini configuration')
[...]
```

### config.yml

```
databases:
    logs: postgresql://botcrypto:botcrypto@127.0.0.1:5432/logs
    ohlc: postgresql://botcrypto:botcrypto@127.0.0.1:5432/ohlc
```

**usage**

```
SETTINGS=config.yml alembic upgrade head
```

Hope it can helps !

Answer (score 4):

Building on top of @dimmg's answer:

You can overwrite the `sqlalchemy.url` specified in `alembic.ini` in the `env.py` file.

### Single Database

#### `env.py`

Insert

```
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', <db_uri>)
```

where <db_uri> can be loaded from the environment or config file.

### Multi-Database

#### `env.py`

Assuming you a have multi-database setup with databases `db_a` and `db_b`, insert

```
config.set_section_option('db_a', 'sqlalchemy.url', <db_uri_a>)
config.set_section_option('db_b', 'sqlalchemy.url', <db_uri_b>)
```

where <db_uri_a> and <db_uri_b> are the database URI for `db_a` and `db_b`, respectively, and can be loaded from the environment or config file.

### Note

Make sure to also indicate in the `alembic.ini` file that the parameters specified there are overwritten in in the `env.py` file. The section in which the `sqlalchemy.url`s are specified could even be removed entirely for all DB's for which the URI is overwritten in `env.py`.

This will hopefully save you or collaborators some confusion when returning to the project later.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the existing answers, the [alembic tutorial](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) has this to say:

> - `sqlalchemy.url` - A URL to connect to the database via SQLAlchemy. This configuration value is only used if the env.py file calls upon them; in the “generic” template, the call to `config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")` in the `run_migrations_offline()` function and the call to `engine_from_config(prefix="sqlalchemy.")` in the `run_migrations_online()` function are where this key is referenced. If the SQLAlchemy URL should come from some other source, such as from environment variables or a global registry, or if the migration environment makes use of multiple database URLs, the developer is encouraged to alter the env.py file to use whatever methods are appropriate in order to acquire the database URL or URLs.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a file called `.env` and store the url in it with:

```
DB_URL = <your_database_url>
```

2. Modify `sqlalchemy.url` in `alembic.ini` file as follow:

```
sqlalchemy.url = %(DB_URL)s
```

3. Load `DB_URL` into the `env.py` generated by alembic with:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

config = context.config

config.set_main_option("DB_URL", os.environ["DB_URL"])
```

4. Continue with creating migration versions (e.g. `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Baseline"`)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

env.py(filename)

def get_url():
   return os.getenv("PERSISTENCE_DSN")


def run_migrations_online():
   connectable = create_engine(get_url())
   with connectable.connect() as connection:
       """
       Configure migration context
       1. Pass our models metadata
       2. Set schema for alembic_version table
       3. Load all available schemas
       """
       context.configure(
           connection=connection,
           target_metadata=target_metadata,
           version_table_schema=target_metadata.schema,
           include_schemas=True,
           include_name=include_name,

       )
       with context.begin_transaction():
           """
           By default search_path is setted to "$user",public 
           that why alembic can't create foreign keys correctly
           """
           context.execute('SET search_path TO public')
           context.run_migrations().env(filename)
 
    PERSISTENCE_DSN='postgresql://test:test@127.0.0.1:5432/test'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way would be to get the DB URI used inside the project. Get it however it has been used there.

Like my fastapi project used to load it from .env and then creating the sqlalchemy Base and all.  I just used the same function here.

```py
    from backend.database import get_db_uri
    
    # this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
    # access to the values within the .ini file in use.
    config = context.config
    
    
    config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', get_db_uri())
```